# Where did the jquery selection options go on jsfiddle.net?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Maybe I am not seeing this, and maybe this is not the correct place to ask this question, but recently been visiting jsfiddle.net and noticed that the jquery selections and jqueryui selections have vanished.  Is this no longer available to choose from automatically?  What happened to these?

I did much of my testing on this site because it was simple to start for that main reason, but now it seems that putting in the url for a jquery CDN and other CDN's is required instead of just selecting them.

Is there a new way to select these Libraries?  Or was this removed for, perhaps, legal reasons?

In the Settings I am seeing this:

[image: jsFiddle.net Settings]

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: The Settings is not helpful though...  No options in there either.

Comment: you have to add the jQuery library in the external resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `JAVASCRIPT` button on the JS panel:

[image]

Comment: OMG, thanks, that is soooo awesome!  It's so much better this way!  Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @SolomonClosson yea, the new way is better. Cheers :)

Comment: You could also have SCSS in the previus version :D

Comment: I didn't know that, but now it's more obvious and flexible this new way.